# Function call within ajax success isn't working

Tags: html, ajax, html-table

I have a function call inside of the success function of ajax. The problem is that I'm not getting any indication that the outside function is actually being called. I've even added an alert to it to make sure it wasn't being properly called. I'm fairly new to html and ajax so any help is greatly appreciated.

AJAX Function:

```
  <script>
$(function() {
    $('.update_btn').click(function() {
        var $row = $(this).closest("tr"),
        $tds = $row.find("td:nth-child(1)");
        var file_name = $tds.text()
        $row.remove()
        $.ajax({
            url: '/database',
            data: {f : file_name},
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(msg) {
               newRow(msg);
            }
        });

    });
});

  </script>
```

Outside Function:

```
<script>
    function newRow(msg) {
        alert(msg.status)
        switch (msg.status) {
            case 'Safe':
                 var tr = '<tr class="c_table">' +
                 '<td>' + msg.file_name + '</td>' : '<td>' + msg.status + '</td>' : '<td>' + msg.time + '</td></tr>';
                 $('#c_table').append(tr);
                 break;
            case 'Threat':
                 var tr = '<tr class="c_table">' +
                 '<td>' + msg.file_name + '</td>' : '<td>' + msg.status + '</td>' : '<td>' + msg.time + '</td></tr>';
                 $('#c_table').append(tr);
                 break;
            case 'Queued':
                 var tr = '<tr class="p_table">' +
                 '<td>' + msg.file_name + '</td>' : '<td>' + msg.status + '</td>' : '<td>' + msg.time + '</td></tr>';
                 $('#p_table').append(tr);
                 break;
        }
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: Are you getting a status of 200 in your ajax call? You can check that in javascript console > network tab of your browser.

Comment: This is an opportune time to open your browser's debugging tools.  With them you can debug, observe the AJAX HTTP request/response, etc.  Is there any error at all on the debugging console?  Is the AJAX request made?  What is the server's response?  (Note: If the response is an error code then your AJAX code has no error handler.)  If the server is returning what you expect, place a debugging breakpoint in your `success` handler.  What's in `msg`?  Is the function called?  What happens?

Comment: @Kumar Yes, I do get a status 200.

Comment: I've added an alert to the success function and confirmed that I'm getting the appropriate response in msg

Comment: @EdselNorwood: So the function *is* being called and the value *does* contain what you expect?  Then... what's the problem?

Comment: @David The problem wasn't that success wasn't being called. The issue is that the function that I'm calling **within** success isn't working (or being called at all).

Comment: @EdselNorwood: The `alert` is in the function that you claim isn't being called, and you claim that the `alert` is happening.  Please clarify the problem.  Also, you've still yet to step through this code in a debugger and define specifically what's happening and what's failing.  Doing that would eliminate all of your guessing and actually pinpoint the problem, if there even is one.

Comment: @David I added an alert to the success to ensure that is was being called. That one works but the one inside the other function doesn't. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @EdselNorwood: Sprinkling your code with `alert`s isn't debugging.  Debugging is debugging.  Honestly, take a look at your browser's developer tools.  They are *a critical part* of web development.  Place a debugging breakpoint in your `success` handler, and then step through the code line by line as it executes.  If an error is encountered, look at the browser's developer console.  Basically, stop *guessing* and start *observing*.

Comment: @David: As I said, I'm not familiar with HTML or AJAX so I figured the issue was some logical or syntax error on my part. Either way thanks for the input, I'll take a look at the code and properly debug it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was a syntax error in the outside function. When setting `var tr` in the switch cases there was a `:` where a `+` should've been. I'm not really how that happened.

Fixed code:

```
  <script>
    function newRow(msg) {
        alert(msg.status)
        switch (msg.status) {
            case 'Safe':
                 var tr = '<tr class="c_table">' + '<td>' + msg.file_name + '</td>' + '<td>' + msg.status + '</td>' + '<td>' + msg.time + '</td></tr>';
                 $('#c_table').append(tr);
                 break;
            case 'Threat':
                 var tr = '<tr class="c_table">' + '<td>' + msg.file_name + '</td>' + '<td>' + msg.status + '</td>' + '<td>' + msg.time + '</td></tr>';
                 $('#c_table').append(tr);
                 break;
            case 'Queued':
                 var tr = '<tr class="p_table">' + '<td>' + msg.file_name + '</td>'  + '<td>' + msg.status + '</td>' + '<td>' + msg.time + '</td></tr>';
                 $('#p_table').append(tr);
                 break;
        }
    }
  </script>
```